# whats alternative to UDID?

Tags: android, ios

I am developing a android application  for a exploratory project using client server architecture. I thought of using UDID but now its replaced by new "Advertising ID", but in my application, i need to store data about user on server with some unique ID per device.
so what should i use as alternative to UDID? 
i checked open UDID but that is also outdated now.
Using "advertising ID" imposes problem of consistency when user clears/resets his advertising ID.

Request the community to help me out.

Comment: Even you can't use UDID of iPhone now! :)

Comment: May be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/5429930/1479798

Answer (score 0):

There is also `identifierForVendor` see more in apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)

Comment: Thank you , but i am in need of alternative for android presently

Answer (score 0):

You can register the device with the **Google Cloud Messaging** platform.

When you register the device correctly this gives you back a **register id** that´s **unique** for every device.

> http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

**UPDATE**

You can also, if you haven't tried it out yet, to user the telephony manager to get the device identifier.

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

On iOS you can try this

```
NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

This will give you a unique id per app.

Comment: I am new to GCM. I will definitely try it out. But using GCM registration ID is a workaround. Lets dig to find solution without any dependency(in this case GCM). Thanks.

Comment: Does GCM register id remain same always?

Comment: @Williams it should return a unique identifier for that app and should stay the same since it will be using it to send notifications.

Comment: @axierjhtjz UDID to uniquely identify the device, if you are considering the package name which unique identify the app then both are totally different case. OP want here unique identity to identify the device

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about Android :

But Check these :

[GeneratingDeviceSpecificSerialNo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464881/generating-device-specific-serial-number/13839341#13839341) &&  [HEre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464881/generating-device-specific-serial-number/13839341#13839341)

In IOS :

```
-identifierForVendor
```

1. ID that is identical between apps from the same developer.
2. Erased with removal of the last app for that Team ID.
3. Backed up.

For more Info [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836225/ios6-udid-what-advantages-does-identifierforvendor-have-over-identifierforadve)

Comment: Google account name does not identify device uniquely. one may own more than one android device and uses same account in all of his/her devices